# Can Android issue call to our native c code?

Tags: android

I know there are many post relative to this topic, but I didn't find any of them helpful.

My question is: Can android issue a call to our native c code? I am aware of using JNI to call native c code, but in this case there is some Java code which gets executed first and then it calls our native code.

I am interested in writing an entire android app in 'c' where in my native code will be executed when the application starts and there is not Java code which i have to write that gets executed before my 'c' code.

For example, when we start an android app, the execution starts from Oncreate() and then using JNI we call our native code. Is there any way where-in our native code gets the control first when the app starts. Or like Android itself will issue JNI call to my native c code when the app starts. So in this way I can write entire app in 'c'.

Comment: It's not very clear to me why JNI doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: Project requirements, sorry can't disclose it further..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you downloaded [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) and try some sample code inside? There is a sample called "native-activity". Probably it is what you want

Comment: Hey thanks, its working for me. One more question now: what is the starting point of the application when we use native-activity. Is it ANativeActivity_onCreate() ?

Comment: void android_main(struct android_app* state)

Answer (score 0):

After a quick google found this...Have a look through the android documentation on [NativeActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html). Looks like it may be along the lines of what you are trying to do.